# Why is a continuous Lévy process twice integrable?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, levy-processes

In his textbook "Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie" (de Gruyter, 2008), Jochen Wengenroth shows (p. 144) that if $(X_t)_{t\in[0,\infty)}$ is a continuous, real-valued Lévy process with $X_t\in \mathcal{L}_2$ for all $t \in [0, \infty)$, then $X$ is a Brownian motion with drift. He remarks, but does not prove, that the stipulation that $X_t \in \mathcal{L}_2$ is redundant. Why is it redundant? Are all Lévy processes twice integrable, or only the continuous ones?

Comment: "Are all Lévy processes twice integrable, or only the continuous ones?" Neither nor. There are Lévy processes which are not twice integrable, but on the other hand there are also Lévy processes with jumps which are twice integrable (so continuity is sufficient, but not necessary for having finite second moments). In fact, any Lévy processes with (uniformly) bounded jumps has moments of arbitrary order. Are you familiar with the strong Markov property of Lévy processes?

Comment: @saz: The textbook that I'm reading proves the following theorem (7.14, p. 144), which it refers to as the "Strong Lévy-property". Is this the strong Markov property of Lévy processes that you referred to? "Let $X=(X)_{t\in[0,\infty)}$ be an $\mathcal{F}$-Lévy-process and let $\tau$ be a real-valued $\mathcal{F}$-stopping time. Then $Y_t := X_{\tau+t}-X_\tau$ is a process that is independent of $\mathcal{F}_\tau^+$, and $Y\overset{d}{=} X$."

Comment: Yes, exactly. There is a proof which relies mainly on the strong Markov property, see Lemma 8.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.00251 (don't worry, this is not a research article, but a lecture series aimed at master/phd students).

Comment: @saz: I've only now got around to taking up on your suggestion and read Lemma 8.2. Thanks for your helpfulness! The proof looks straightforward on the surface, but when I got down to trying to justify to myself the various steps, I've reached an impasse. Could you please assist me in resolving it?

Comment: @saz: The problem is that, for some $n\in\{2,3,\dots\}$ it may happen that $\tau_{n-1}(\omega)=\infty$ for some $\omega$, in which case $\tau_n(\omega)-\tau_{n-1}(\omega)$ is not well defined. Moreover, even if we understand the expression $\tau_n-\tau_{n-1}$ as $(\tau_n-\tau_{n-1})\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau_{n-1}\neq\infty\}}$ or as $(\tau_n-\tau_{n-1})\mathbb{1}_{\cap_{k=1}^\infty\{\tau_k\neq\infty\}}$, we still have to contend with the claims that $\tau_{n+1}-\tau_n\sim\tau_1$ and that $\tau_n-\tau_{n-1}\perp\mathcal{F}^X_{\tau_{n-1}}$.

Comment: @saz: Another possible way to attack this problem is to adjust the underlying probability space so as to consider only those $\omega$'s for which $\wedge_{k=1}^\infty \tau_k(\omega)\neq\infty$. But then, is the correspondingly adjusted stochastic process $(X_t)_{t\in[0,\infty)}$ still a Lévy process, and are the correspondingly adjusted random times $\tau_k$ still stopping times?

Comment: @saz: I've opened a separate question for this issue [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872573/a-proof-by-rené-schilling-that-a-continuous-lévy-process-is-integrable).

Comment: I'll have a look at it, but it might take a while.

Comment: @saz: OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to indicate an answer to what I think is your real question ("Is there a direct way to show that a continuous Lévy process is square integrable?") A detailed discussion of this and much more, using stochastic calculus, can be found on Geo. Lowther's blog, specifically https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/09/15/processes-with-independent-increments/ .

Here is a sketch of the portion of Lowther's argument relevant to your question. First, by virtue of the stationary independent increments of $X$, there is a function $\psi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ such that $\Bbb E[\exp(ibX_t)]=\exp(t\psi(b))$ for all real $b$ and all $t>0$. Moreover, $U_t:=\exp(ibX_t-t\psi(b)$ is a martingale. From this, by taking logarithms and applying Ito's formula, is follows that $X$ is a continuous semimartingale. Notice that $|U_t|=|\exp(-t\psi(b))|$ is uniformly bounded on finite time intervals, so $U$ is even a square-integrable martingale. Likewise, $|U_t^{-1}|$ is uniformly bounded on finite time intervals, so (using Ito's formuula for the second equality below)
$$
M_t:=ibX_t-t\psi(b)-{1\over 2}\langle X\rangle_t
=\int_0^t U^{-1}_s\,dU_s
$$
is a square-integrable martingale. Finally, 
$$
X_t=-ib^{-1}\left[M_t+t\psi(b)+{1\over 2}\langle X\rangle_t\right]
$$
is square integrable. (Observe that $\langle X\rangle_t$ is non-random because $X$ has stationary independent increments.)

I do not know of a more direct argument.

Comment: Thanks. This argument is currently a little too advanced for me. I hope tol come back and read this answer in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The only continuous Lévy processes are Brownian motion (with or without drift). There are Lévy processes that are not square-integrable; viz. the Cauchy processes.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not quite answer my question, since the textbook I mentioned relies on the fact that a continuous Lévy process is twice integrable to prove that it must be a Brownian motion with drift, so to claim that the reason why a continuous Lévy processe is twice integrable is because it is a Brownian motion is circular logic.

Comment: "Why is it redundant?" Because every continuous real-valued Lévy process is already square integrable.  "Are all Lévy processes twice integrable...?" No: all of the stable Lévy processes are non-square-integrable. In general if $\nu$ is the Lévy measure of the process $X$, then $X_t$ is square integrable (for each $t>0$) if and only if $\int_{\mathbf R} x^2\,\nu(dx)<\infty$. (And of course this condition holds trivially for Brownian motion because $\nu=0$ then.)